# IIS 10 connect to a WebApi project using IP address and not host name

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2016

- IIS 10, WebAPI 2, Windows Server 2016

I have deployed my application to the server and have an IIS binding of:

[image]

The host name is not world accessible so I added an entry to hosts to map it:

blah.foo.com 10.4.2.116

Using http://blah.foo.com locally on the machine I can make a connection to both the underlying MVC and WebAPI.

However if I go to 10.4.2.116 IIS returns a 404. So my question is how do I configure IIS to respond on that internal 10.x.x.x IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an empty host name and then Type: HTTP, Port: 80, IP Address: 10.4.2.116 is how you do this in IIS GUI.